# Angular - convert to lowercase in an input field

Tags: angular, typescript

i have an email input, i want when i write in the input uppercase letters it converts them into lowercase letters

i tried this method but it shows me an errer

> ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
<input type="text" formControlName="mail" (ngModelChange)="toLowerCase($event)">

private toLowerCase(event): void {
    this.cmOrganizationForm.get('mail').setValue(event.toLowerCase());
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please don't use `ngModelChange` event when you are using Reactive forms.

---

Listen to `valueChanges` subscription of your form control and set the value under the subscription, with `emitEvent` as false, this will not emit `valueChanges` event again.

Try this out, this will not `emit` valueChanges event again

```
private ngOnInit(): {
  this.cmOrganizationForm.get('mail').valueChanges.subscribe((event) => {
     this.cmOrganizationForm.get('mail').setValue(event.toLowerCase(), {emitEvent: false});
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve what you want without event:

In your css add

`input[type="text"] { text-transform: lowercase; }`

and in `.ts` file use `this.cmOrganizationForm.get('mail').toLowerCase();`

Answer (score 1):

we need to remove modelChange event emitter that should be used in Template Driven Form 'ngModel'.

**Template:**

```
<input type="text" formControlName="mail">
```

**Component:**

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.form.get('mail').valueChanges.subscribe(event => {
     this.form.get('mail').setValue(event.toLowerCase(), {emitEvent: false});
  });
}
```

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wp4tim?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

this function in angular 6 for underscore and lowercase:

```
 underscore(selectkpi){
    this.selectedUnderKpi = selectkpi.replace(' ', '_').toLowerCase();
    var a = this.selectedUnderKpi
    console.log("ini = ",a);
  }
```